# Using LIKE in bindParam for a MySQL PDO Query

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I've read multiple examples on how these queries should be written but I'm struggling to get this specific like to run when using `bindParam`

Would this be the correct way to match usernames that begin with a?

```
$term = "a";
$term = "'$term%'";

$sql = "SELECT username 
        FROM `user` 
        WHERE username LIKE :term 
        LIMIT 10";      

$core = Connect::getInstance();

$stmt = $core->dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':term', $term, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

No, you don't need the inner single quotes so just `$term = "$term%";`

The statement you're running now would try to match `'a%'` instead of `a%`

bindParam will make sure that all string data is automatically properly quoted when given to the SQL statement.

Comment: Here is a sample code: https://gist.github.com/arsho/a203e7bc156ea566587361a76038f020

Answer (score 6):

You can use bindValue , suppose you are having a **$query = "search string"**

```
$stmt->bindValue(':term', $query.'%'); // this will do like search for "search term XXXXX"
```

similarly

```
$stmt->bindValue(':term', '%'.$query.'%');
```

or

```
$stmt->bindValue(':term', '%'.$query);
```