# Is it possible to bindParam WHERE name like %:name%

Tags: php, sql, pdo, bindparam

I'm testing a small search feature:

But I've come across an error that I cannot seem to solve. You can see the PDO query here:

```
$search = "test1"; //later to be changes to $_POST ['search'];

$sql = "SELECT id, name FROM clients WHEE name like %:name% order by id LIMIT 5";
$stm = $db->prepare ( $sql );
$stm->bindParam ( ":name" , $search);
$result = $stm->execute ();
```

As you can see, I'm trying to bind the parameter `%:name%` from my query, but I don't know if that's actually possible?

I receive the error:

> Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]:.....

And I can see in the error that '' has been put around test1 %'test1'%

Is what I'm trying possible, or do I need to do something like this?

```
$query = "SELECT id, name FROM clients WHEE name like :name order by id LIMIT 5";

$sql->execute(array(":name" => "%" .$search . "%"));
```

Comment: This question already have an answer checkout the URL.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068230/using-like-in-bindparam-for-a-mysql-pdo-query

Comment: You've misspelled `WHERE` as `WHEE`.

Comment: I rolled back your later edits as they fixed the issue that the comment and answer helped you to solve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
LIKE CONCAT('%', :name, '%')
```