# PDO statement not retrieving any data

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using something like this to get values from my database, but it's not returning anything. No errors, but also no data when I know there should be. I'm sure I have some syntax error, but can't figure out where:

```
$search_crit = $_POST['search_items'];
$sql1 = "SELECT `Provider Name`, `State Abbrv`, `zip_code` FROM `myTable` 
where `Provider Name` like '%:criteria%' group by `Provider Name`";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql1);
$stmt->bindParam(':criteria', $search_crit, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
$stmt->execute();
$result1 = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

In this case, `$search_crit` is a string entered by the user on the front end. I've ran this query by "hardcoding" a value in for `:criteria`, so I know it works in principle, but can't figure out what my issue is when I try to pass the value with PDO.

Comment: that will depend on what the POST array returns and whether if it's set/not empty. check for errors all around

Comment: It's not an array...just a single value like "Smith" and it definitely is set, as I can do a `var_dump` and see it.

Comment: `$_POST` is a.k.a. post array.

Comment: I found your problem `'%:criteria%'` the colon

Comment: like query with pdo needs  little customization as compared to simple matches. See the question i linked to yours

Comment: See @Hanky웃Panky's link and http://stackoverflow.com/q/11068230/ that Q&A.

Comment: Switched to this per the question, but still getting nothing back: `$stmt->execute(':criteria', '%'.$search_crit.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);`

Comment: You could just do `$sql1 = "SELECT \`Provider Name\`, \`State Abbrv\`, \`zip_code\` FROM \`myTable\` 
where \`Provider Name\` like ? group by \`Provider Name\`";` and `$stmt->execute(array('%'.$search_crit.'%'));`. See example #6, http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php.

Comment: Jonmirch execute takes an array not a string. chris85 uses that correctly in the comment above